# Creating a txt file fails with php

Tags: php, file-io

I am trying to create a file and write a message in a folder called debug:

```
 function debug($report){
   $file="/debug/debug.txt";
   file_put_contents($file,$report,FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
 }
```

The debug folder is in my root directory. But file fails to be created.. Why?

Comment: Have you set the correct permissions for that `debug` folder?

Comment: check the permission ? And post your error here

Comment: add `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` to the beginning of your php file or change it in `php.ini`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will open **all** the permissions for the folder.

```
chmod('PATH_TO_FOLDER',0777);
```

Depending on what exactly you want to do with that folder, you might consider giving it slightly more limited permissions that allow only specific users to read/write to it.

Here are some other examples taken from the PHP manual - http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

```
<?php
// Read and write for owner, nothing for everybody else
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0600);

// Read and write for owner, read for everybody else
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0644);

// Everything for owner, read and execute for others
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0755);

// Everything for owner, read and execute for owner's group
chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0750);
?>
```

Comment: is this the way to write it:  chmod('/debug',0777);

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to pass an absolute path.  Try `chmod($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/debug',0777)`

Answer (score 1):

This is really a codicil to [Lix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/558021/lix)'s answer.

The most frequent reason for this is when you are running you scripts under Apache using mpd_php5, since your php process will be running as apache UID (`www-data` or whatever).  However, by default your debug directory will be own by your account with 755 permissions.

I would suggest that it is bad practice to set the permissions to 777 as this will allow anyone to create files in your directory, but instead *temporarily* set the permissions to 777 then use a Q&D script to create a `debug/logs` and set its permissions to 755, before returning the debug directory to 755.

You will find that the `debug/logs` directory is now own by the Apache UID, and can be written to by any Apache process.

One wrinkle here is that you will need to use a script to delete old debug files as your own account won't have the privilege to do this.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing wrong with that code, if errors not shown maybe caused be php configuration. 
Please see at Error Reporting [Error Report](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php).

Generally it may caused by permission ( see permission on debug folder )

Comment: Both [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325751/creating-a-txt-file-fails-with-php#comment14909483_11325751) **and** [permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325751/creating-a-txt-file-fails-with-php#comment14909342_11325751) have been suggested.  Please read the post before attempting to answer.